# Cannot make 5 consecutive "joins" in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008

I have this rather complex query in SQL server 2008:

```
declare @LanguageID as int = 1

select k.datePublish, k.dateEditing, k.dateTables

from TableAreasLevel1 as areaL1 

inner join TableAreasLevel2 as areaL2 
on areaL1.LanguageID = areaL2.LanguageID and 
areaL1.CodeAreaLevel1 = areaL2.CodeAreaLevel1

inner join TableAreasLink as link
on areaL2.CodeAreaLevel1 = link.CodeAreaLevel1 and
areaL2.CodeAreaLevel2 = link.CodeAreaLevel2 and

inner join TableProducts as tblProds
on tblProds.CodeAreaLevel1 = areaL1.CodeAreaLevel1 and
tblProds.CodeAreaLevel2 = areaL2.CodeAreaLevel2

inner join TableSI_Products as prod 
on prod.SiAreaCode = link.SiAreaCode

inner join TableCalendar as k
on k.KodTableSI_Products = tblProds.KodTableSI_Products

where areaL1.LanguageID = @LanguageID and 
prod.Code = 'some string' and 
k.LanguageID = @LanguageID and 
tblProds.LanguageID = @LanguageID;
```

I am trying to develop the same query in LINQ, but I get error when I try join the table TableProducts, i.e the third consecutive join.

Here is my LINQ query:

```
List<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime, DateTime>> dates = (from areaL1 in gpe.TableAreasLevel1 
    join areaL2 in gpe.TableAreasLevel2 
        on new { areaL1.CodeAreaLevel1, areaL1.LanguageID } equals 
            new { areaL2.CodeAreaLevel1, areaL2.LanguageID } 

    join link in gpe.TableAreasLink 
        on new { areaL2.CodeAreaLevel1, areaL2.CodeAreaLevel2, areaL2.RbrOblastNivo2} equals 
            new {link.CodeAreaLevel1, link.CodeAreaLevel2}

    join tblProds in gpe.TableProducts
        on tblProds. // The name tblProds is not in the scope of the left side of 'equals'

    );
```

Is the problem connected with how the tables are designed or, something else I should check for?

Any ideas, why **tblProds** is not visible in the scope of the LINQ query?

Comment: Something always screams modelling mistake when you have multiple tables with the same names, distinguished solely by a number at the end.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes people here just want the software finished :) you might be right actually.

Comment: Gonna have to investigate more.

Comment: Why don't you switch the left and right sides of the equality predicate?

Comment: How is join to `TableAreasLink` ever gonna produce a match when you have different types on each side of the equals operator? (one with 2 properties and one with 3)

Answer (score 0):

You are using Query as your guide something like:

```
on k.KodTableSI_Products = tblProds.KodTableSI_Products
```

but take a look at your linq:

```
on new { areaL1.CodeAreaLevel1, areaL1.LanguageID } equals
```

it has two fields. I think its not a good idea.

linq join something like

```
var dates = (from areaL1 in gpe.TableAreasLevel1 
    join areaL2 in gpe.TableAreasLevel2 
        on areaL1.PKFields  equals areaL2.PKFields
          where areaL1.CodeAreaLevel1== areaL2.CodeAreaLevel1 && areaL1.LanguageID =  areaL2.LanguageID
Select new YournewClass{YournewClass.Field1=areaL1.fields1, And so on}

)
```

You can do to join the other tables with aliases.

Sorry need to go for now.
I'm giving you an idea.
Hope it helps.